# "Whn U Ck Me, U WL Fnd Me Sez da Lord." in this picture (publicity)

Tags: single-word-requests, abbreviations, internet

Does the style (if it is) shown in the picture below have a particular name?

[image: Poster outside a church with bible quote in textspeak]

> “Whn U Ck Me, U WL Fnd Me Sez da Lord”

In full: *When you seek me, you will find me says the Lord.*

Comment: Fascinating. Where did you see this/take this picture?

Comment: @Mitch that's a polite way to put it.

Comment: I definitely misread this as something vulgar on the front page. You know what, on reading it again, I still think it's vulgar, it just isn't obscene.

Comment: @Mitch According to [Flikr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kronoc/185647690/) it was "taken on July 9, 2006 in East End, London, England, GB."

Comment: It’s certainly a lot shorter than the version I learned: [“If with all your hearts ye truly seek me, ye shall ever surely find me, thus saith our God.”](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N22SkeJKA4M)

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: OK I'm slow. with the intertubes thing...how did you find -that- info?

Comment: @Mitch Start with Google Image search (you can drag the image to the search window with a HTML5 browser such as Chrome). After the image search results, it's some old-fashioned surfing to find the source. This pic wasn't in too many places, so it was quick to find.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: OK Goo-Fu master, what does '((H)))' and 'UGoTaBIEu' mean (both on that poster)?

Comment: @Mitch I believe either or both refer to the company's name, and that 'UGoTaBIEu' resolves to roughly *you've got to be you*.

Comment: @Mitch '((H)))' is [Hugs](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/textmessageabbreviations_02.asp) and "You gotta believe" (the last letter is a v in [Chicago type face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(typeface))). [Here's](http://www.chrisbeach.co.uk/core/scripts/entryViewer.php?ID=5016) another set of riddles.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I'm not up for a riddle.  :)

Answer (score 15):

This shorthand is known as [textspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language).

> SMS language or textese (also known as txt-speak, txtese, chatspeak,
>   txt, txtspk, txtk, txto, texting language, txt lingo, SMSish,
>   txtslang,or txt talk) is a term for the abbreviations and slang most
>   commonly used due to the necessary brevity of mobile phone text
>   messaging, in particular the widespread SMS (Short Message Service)
>   communication protocol.

Comment: True, but that doesn't account for 'da Lord'. So some kind of AAVE as well, perhaps?

Comment: But *da* is two keystrokes for "the". Both *d* and *a* are the first letters on their respective keys. Only *d* would be shorter (and is used for "the" in some dialects of Txtspk).

Comment: I disagree. Not that the average texter would be likely to send this exact message anyway, but if someone did, I suggest they'd *never* keep switching case as in the example here. Or be likely to use **Ck** for *seek*, for example. Yes, it's partly an advertiser's impression of textese. But it ain't the real thing, by a long shot.

Comment: The plain English bit at the bottom is your big clue that this is in fact what is going on. A picture of a phone keyboard with "Free messaging...Chat with God!".

Comment: @FumbleFingers The capitalization is pretty normal, in my experience, even if the abbreviations aren't; seeing this stirs up memories of fighting with several phones that had T9 predictive text and would somehow get themselves back on what I can only call the Suddenly Capitalize Every Word setting or the ReMembr typos UnexpectedLY setting.

Comment: It's a bad imitation (I'd expect "ull" for you'll. or something similar instead of "U WL") and as mentioned the capitalisation is implausible - in early texting you might do all caps, later all lower case, depending on how the phone does things by default.

Answer (score 2):

At one time, back before there was any even arguably good reason for it, this was called [Princespeak](http://www.startribune.com/entertainment/music/96575094.html).

Comment: I don't see anything relevant at that link. Can you explain what association Prince has with abbreviated writing?

Comment: @Marthaª: Search for the word princespeak in it.  Prince started using that crap way back; remember "Nothing Compares 2 U"?

Comment: No, I don't. More to the point, I shouldn't have to: your answer should be self-contained. Links can support an answer, but they are not an answer on their own.

Comment: @chaos I don't think Prince ever recorded that, he just gave it to [Sinead O'Connor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_Compares_2_U).  A better example might be [I Would Die 4 U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Would_Die_4_U).