# Is there a term to the practice of over-inflating big words like 'edumecation' and 'philosphization'?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

Morphologically speaking, I suppose this is the practice of adding meaningless affixes in order to make the word appear more grandiose.

Perhaps more common in AAVE, especially the word 'edumecate'. Often used to satirical or mocking effect.

Alternatives include [educamate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/educamate), [edumacate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/edumacate), like for example in MF DOOM's song [Vomitspit](https://genius.com/24298296):

> Well edumacated, he heard it when he meditated /
> In deep theta, let her hate, the creep played her

I feel like this is a practice common enough to warrant its own name as a discrete stylistic device. But I can't find it.

Comment: I now see that I asked a similar (but different) question 5 years ago; it is probably related to [eye dialect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424637/is-there-a-word-for-intentional-misspelling-as-a-literary-device)

Comment: While "philosphization" might be the result of an AAVE mispronunciation and thus be eye-dialect, *edumecate* is a new word. I think your question may need more detail.

Comment: Perhaps I've wrongly generalized, if you do not recognize the same pattern. (I suppose [cacography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography) & [sensational spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling) might fit the bill.)

Comment: It's a subdivision of gobbledygook. Stanley Unwin used such language ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Unwin_(comedian))), often less easy to interpret.

Comment: For neologism (new words) used by technocrats, you may refer to **Orwellian newspeak**.

Comment: *in order to make the word appear more grandiose.* Rather *to make the **speaker** appear grander, more sophisticated, more educated, more ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following ***[site](https://slangdefine.org/e/edumacate-f3d.html),*** it is a way to Homerize words, that is  to treat or put it in a Homeric style.

> Other examples include Gradumacation, Saxamophone, Trampampoline and Translamacation

> "Can you edumacate me in the ways of the saxamophone?"
> "Let me translamacate it for you while we play on the trampampoline"

(slangdefine.org)

Comment: Wow! Yes, exactly what I meant! Thank you. But it seems to be a neologism particular to this website?

Comment: Is this Homer as in Homer, or Homer as in Homer Simpson? Again, more detail is needed.

Comment: Reckon: obviously Homer the poet, that is to render the word more epic or poetic (perhaps even to fit the metrum?)

Comment: I don't think it's obvious at all. The answer should demonstrate "Homeric style", not merely copy from a website which seems to have the reliability of Urban Dictionary.

Comment: It does indeed to be niche to one-off. Looking up 'homerization', UD does offer a definition, but it's nothing to do with morphology.

Comment: Please cite a more reliable source, one that doesn't refer to the word's users as "feral."

Comment: @Maarten I'd have assumed obviously Homer Simpson - saxamophone in particular is very well associated with Homer Simpson, as is [tramampoline/trambampoline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_VTvQLAfaE).

Answer (score 1):

In the Renaissance period it was fashionable to invent long or complicated words, mostly based on Latin. These days they are called **inkhorn words** or **inkhornisms**.

Comment: [This discussion {Michael Quinion at WorldWideWords}](https://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/inkhorn.htm) certainly includes 'fatigate: to fatigue' (but the former, the candidate, never made it into the lexicon). But most other candidates are not based on single existing words with the same meaning / 'meaning'.

Answer (score 0):

> Linguistic **flatulence**

would be a plain (if educated) English description of this phenomenon, although the term has a wider compass than this particular abomination.